# how to include public resources to typo3 extbase extension

Tags: php, typo3, fluid, extbase

I'm building an extension that creates a backend module that enables be_users to resize images.
I'm trying to add / include css and javascript files by using the pageRenderer but the files are never included I can only apply css if add it directly in the fluid Template using a style tag and include the javascript file with a script tag.

I tried something like this in the controller

`protected $pageRenderer;`

....

```
    $this->pageRenderer = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Page\\PageRenderer');
    $this->pageRenderer->addCssFile('/typo3conf/ext/extKey/Resources/Public/css/styles.css');
    $this->pageRenderer->loadJquery();
```

also tried with a viewHelper

```
namespace Vendor\ExtKey\ViewHelpers;

class AddJsFileViewHelper extends \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\Be\AbstractBackendViewHelper {

    public function render() {
        $doc = $this->getDocInstance();
        $pageRenderer = $doc->getPageRenderer();
        $pageRenderer->loadJquery();
    }
}
```

and in my tempate

```
{namespace pager=Vendor\ExtKey\ViewHelpers}
<f:layout name="Default" />

<f:section name="main">
    <pager:addJsFile />
```

...

still nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the problem was my ViewHelper need to renderChilden and start/end page

current implementation is like this

the ViewHelper

```
namespace Vendor\ExtKey\ViewHelpers;

class AddPublicResourcesViewHelper extends  \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\Be\AbstractBackendViewHelper {

    public function render() {
        $doc = $this->getDocInstance();
        $pageRenderer = $doc->getPageRenderer();
        $extRelPath = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extRelPath("ext_key");

        $pageRenderer->addCssFile($extRelPath . "Resources/Public/css/styles.css");

        $pageRenderer->loadJquery();
        $pageRenderer->addJsFile($extRelPath . "Resources/Public/js/app.js");

        $output = $this->renderChildren();
        $output = $doc->startPage("title") . $output;
        $output .= $doc->endPage();

        return $output;
    }
}
```

the template

```
{namespace pager=Vendor\ExtKey\ViewHelpers}
<f:layout name="Default" />

<f:section name="main">
<pager:addPublicResources />
```

Pagerender::loadJjquery is working and accessible like this

```
TYPO3.jQuery(function($) {

});
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure how you define the template for your backend, but it seems this usually happens using the backend container view helper which already has functions for that:

```
<f:be.container
  addCssFile="{f:uri.resource(path:'css/style.css')}"
  addJsFile="{f:uri.resource(path:'js/scripts.js')}">

  [your templates content]

</f:be.container>
```

Comment: this approach is also working. but happens if you want to include more than one files ?

Comment: Thats not possible with this approach. One might also argue that it shouldn't be done for the sake of simplicity either way, but I realize that at least for JS thats kind of hard if you want to use libraries with your own code. One should note, that there are a few libraries already available via extra options, namely: leadExtJs, loadPrototype and loadScriptaculous. For more info have a look at sysext/fluid/Classes/ViewHelpers/Be/ContainerViewHelper.php

Comment: i reckon it's not a good idea to load libraries in each template but in this case there is only one template and the library im interested in cannot be loaded via the Pagerender::loadJquery()

Comment: You can include more, because it gets an array
https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_install_1_1_view_helpers_1_1_be_1_1_container_view_helper.html

Comment: Also with TYPO3 v7 you can use requirejs to load modules
https://scripting-base.de/blog/requirejs-backend-1.html

Answer (score 3):

In TYPO3 7.6.X, It has to be like following

```
<f:be.container
     includeCssFiles="{style:'{f:uri.resource(path:\'css/style.css\')}'}"
     includeJsFiles="{script:'{f:uri.resource(path:\'js/script.js\')}'}"
    >
<!-- Template Code -->
</f:be.container>
```

> As **includeCssFiles** and **includeJsFiles** requires array to be passed, we
>   can include any number of js and css.