# How to add jquery file on top of the backend

Tags: jquery, typo3

Need to start jquery with `document.ready` to organize some Things in my TYPO3 backend.

I am using for my backend CSS this way:

```
$GLOBALS['TBE_STYLES']['skins']['myext'] = array();
$GLOBALS['TBE_STYLES']['skins']['myext']['name'] = 'My improved t3skin';
$GLOBALS['TBE_STYLES']['skins']['myext']['stylesheetDirectories'] = array(
    'backend' => 'EXT:'.$_EXTKEY.'/Resources/Public/css/backend/'
);
```

is there any similar way to load jquery (backend.js) file?

Regards
Dirk

Comment: Do you have your own backend modul? Have a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045020

Comment: no, this was not helping, .. Need something in T3 CMS 7.6.* which works from TCA / Configuration

Comment: I think you'll need a hook 'renderPreProcess', to include your JS in BackendController.

Comment: as far as I know all TYPO3 core modules include jquery-2.1 in the 7.6 backend by default, so unless it is your specific module or some community extension, you should be able to use it out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, jQuery 2.1.4 is included in TYPO3 v7.6
Have a look at the dsource of your backend, jquery is included here:
typo3/sysext/core/Resources/Public/JavaScript/Contrib/jquery/

And this is how to include your own BE js file:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InsideTypo3Reference/CoreArchitecture/BackendModules/BackendModuleApi/Index.html#tbe-modules

```
$GLOBALS['TBE_MODULES']['_configuration'][$_EXTKEY] = array (
    'jsFiles' => array (
        'EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Resources/Public/Javascript/be-script.js',
    ),
);
```

However, if you want to include the coresponding js for your own BE module, it is best to load js & css in your fluid template via:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Be/Container.html#addjsfile

```
<f:be.container addJsFile="{f:uri.resource(path:'js/custom.js')}">
something
</f:be.container>
```

HTH.